# Batch script to invert the order of a date in file names

Tags: batch-file, rename, batch-rename

I wanted to use a batch script to rename a bunch of files which are using the following name scheme:

```
File 2-9.pdf
File 3-9.pdf
File 4-9.pdf
[...]
```

I want to invert the numbers so that they will become...

```
File 9-2.pdf
File 9-3.pdf
File 9-4.pdf
[...]
```

Normally I would search for the repeating string and replace it, but in this case the string changes with each file, so I don't know how to go about it. Any ideas?

Thank you for reading.

EDIT: I am on Windows, I am seeking to create a .bat file. Something like

```
For %%# in ("file-path") Do (
    Set "File=%%~nx#"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)
```

Comment: Unsure what system or platform you're using since you didn't disclose it, but this would be a good case for Regular Expressions/Pattern Matching.

Comment: Hi Robert, sorry for being unclear. I am on Windows, I wanted a .bat script. I edited the OP to reflect that.

Comment: We could certainly write a batch file based on your "GENERIC" looking file name examples but it probably would not work with your real world file names.

Comment: Hi Squashman, I don't need you to write me a specific script. All I want is some pointers on how to go about writing a script that could identify those three last characters and invert the numbers' positions. I just want to know the logic behind the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

relatively easy. Don't use "search and replace", but use proper tokens and delimiters to split your filenames:

```
@echo off 
for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
  for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=- " %%a in ("%%~nf") do (
    ECHO ren "%%~f" "%%a %%c-%%b%%~xf"
  )
)
```

(Note: remove the `ECHO` after troubleshooting to enable the rename command)