# Rename multiple folders based on their current folder name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am totally new to this batch file and I cannot find any solution to my renaming folder problem. What I have is tons of folders with ID and Company name as folder name and I would like to rename them to Company name first then the ID. Below are what the folders name like and I want to rename them

```
12312 Company Name
24235 Company Name
```

to

```
Company Name 12312
Company Name 24235
```

Is there a way to do it on batch file? If there is can you give me articles/links that can help me achieve what I need?

Thank you!

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46121328/2152082)

Comment: Please open the question for ansers, I have written a script for him that works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read every folder with a `for /d`, split it with a `for /f` into "First Word" and "Rest" and reassemble it:

```
@echo off
for /d %%F in (*) do (
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%A in ("%%F") do (
    ECHO ren "%%F" "%%B %%A"
  )
)
```

Read `For /?` for more info.

(Note: remove the `ECHO` after troubleshooting to enable the rename command)

Comment: This does not take into account if the company name have multiple spaces. Only two "words" are allowed in the company name. Also if the company name have no spaces, you get a space at the end of the folder name.

Comment: @nivs1978: retry. `token 1` (`%%A`)is the ID (first word). `token *` (`%%B`)  is "all the rest". It doesn't matter how many spaces there are.

Comment: @nivs1978  Also I can't replicate the "space issue".